# apache camel - cxfrs handling of multiple requests

Tags: cxf, jax-rs, apache-camel

So I created an endpoint using CXFRS in Apache Camel.  When a user make an API call on that endpoint, I have a lot of chained processes `(.process(new MyProcessors)` (from Processors). All is good and well when I'm just trying it out using consecutive requests.  But the requests seems to take longer when I'm throwing multiple simultaneous requests at the same time.  Is the CXFRS queuing the requests?  I'm not specifying any queue or synchronization here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, CXFRS don't queue the requests, if you are using the http transport from jetty, there is a thread pool for invoking the processors out of box. Maybe you put some synchronise in your processors.